# Negation on RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have such string

```
​String str = "<img src='earth'> ddd earth ggg earth. fff "
```

I want to replace all 'earth' by 'world' except the one in img's src.
Namely I want to get the string

```
<img src='earth'> ddd world ggg world. fff
```

Probably I need an intelligent regex to detect if the word is in src but could not find a way to do it. Or may be negation may help.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is no job for a regex. Parse the string using a html parser and then iterate over the contents of the tags and make your replacement(s).

Comment: @ddimitrov, huh? The OP wants to replace certain words only if they occur inside the tags, I don't see what reluctant quantifiers (or greedy for that matter) have to do with it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the string is well-formed you could use a negative look-behind.

```
s/(?<!src=')earth/world/
```

The `(?<!...)` construct is called a negative look-behind and matches as long as its content is not there.

Comment: I guess the OP also want to exclude the `earth` in `src='... earth ...'`, in which case you'd need a negative look behind in which a `*` or `+` is used which is not supported by many regex engines.

Comment: Yes exactly I tried that 
str.replaceAll(/(?<!src='\w*)earth/, 'world')
it gave me exception.
How should I handle that?

Comment: @javanes, you don't: regex is not applicable here (as I already mentioned :)). See my comment to your question.

Comment: I have just used:
str.replaceAll(/(?<!src='\w{0,500})earth/, 'world')
Thank you Tim, you've teached me about a new feature (look behind)
Thank you Bart, you are right, html parser may be better fit but I like low level.

Comment: @javanes, `\w{0,500}` is still non-obvious look behind which _should_ throw an exception. It may work for you because of a bug in Java's regex engine (see [this](http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6695369)). So realize that by changing your JRE, your code could all of a sudden not work properly because the expected exception is thrown. I'm keeping my fingers crossed that I never get to maintain your code! :)

Comment: @Bart: I’ve come across that very bug in Java before. In some cases it simply increases your run-time by a factor of about 10,000:1. :( Someone had written `(?<^|\s+)` and got themselves into a whole bunch of trouble; no exception but it ran superduperpooperslow.

Comment: Which html parser library do you recommend for Java?

Comment: @javanes, I stay away from HTML as much as I can, so I have little experience with them. I'd start by Googling a bit and trying a few, or ask a new question about it (be sure not too ask a too subjective question: it might be closed because of it).

Comment: @tchrist, well you could do: `((?<=\s..\s)| ... |(?<=\s\s\s)|(?<=\s\s)|(?<=\s))X`, which _is_ legal! :)

Comment: @Bart: I do find myself doing that sort of thing pretty regularly. My standard left-space-edge pattern is indeed `(?:(?<=\A)|(?<=\s))`, which is way asymmetric to its far simpler mirror: `(?=\z|s)`. I know they’ve relaxed this for Perl6, but I don’t expect to go there much before there’s robust Level-2 support for Unicode regexes. Perl5 and ICU (but not Java! nor anything else) both have Level-1 Unicode support, with a few stray bits from Levels 2 and/or 3 thrown in. Google’s Android Java uses JNI to ICU regex libs in lieu of Orasun’s perfectly botched (=Unicode-wretchèd) regex implementation.